# Toggle edit text Typeface

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

Hello Everyone I am making an app where the user can italicize spannable text on a button click.

```
// Captures Contextual Menu Clicks//
public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.bold) {
        // do some stuff
    }

    if (id == R.id.italic) {

        int startSelection = noteContent.getSelectionStart();
        int endSelection = noteContent.getSelectionEnd();
        Spannable spannable = noteContent.getText();

        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC) , startSelection , endSelection , 0);



        StyleSpanRemover spanRemover = new StyleSpanRemover();

        spanRemover.RemoveStyle(spannable,startSelection,endSelection,Typeface.ITALIC);
    }
```

this code makes it italic

```
        int startSelection = noteContent.getSelectionStart();
        int endSelection = noteContent.getSelectionEnd();
        Spannable spannable = noteContent.getText();

        spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC) , startSelection , endSelection , 0);
```

This makes it un-italic

```
        StyleSpanRemover spanRemover = new StyleSpanRemover();

        spanRemover.RemoveStyle(spannable,startSelection,endSelection,Typeface.ITALIC
```

I want the user to click the same button to italicize and un-italicize. What if statment can I use to get what TypeFace the spannable selected words are? That way it knows if to italicize or not

UPDATE: this is what I have now

```
     int startSelection = noteContent.getSelectionStart();
        int endSelection = noteContent.getSelectionEnd();
        Spannable spannable = noteContent.getText();

        StyleSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, StyleSpan.class);

        if (spans.length == 0) {

            spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), startSelection, endSelection , 0);

        } else {

            spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), startSelection, endSelection , 0);
        }
```

even though the code runs the code

```
  spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), startSelection, endSelection , 0);
```

and sets it back to normal. but it wont set spans.length back to zero so I cant italicize it again how to i set spans.length to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, StyleSpan.class)` to see what spans are present in the selection range. Based on that, you can decide whether (and how) to italicize the text. Note the user might highlight a portion that contains *both* normal text and italicized text.

**EDIT**

```
StyleSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, StyleSpan.class);
if (spans.length == 0) {
    // no spans, italicize text here
} else {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: how do I use this in an if statement? Thanks Jordan :)

Comment: If there are no spans in the range, then it must not be italicized. Otherwise, something is italicized.

Comment: I get the premises of that, yes. I just can't figure out how to put it into code, if (getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, StyleSpan.class) = ?) { }